# need to change the class of a label when an error occurs using data annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC 4 with dataannotations and everything works fine but my application has requirement to style the labels in red in case of an error. For example if there is a form field

FirstName followed by a text box. Say the textbox has a required field validation on it. now when the user does not input data the validation fires perfectly however i would like to change the class of the span tag that holds Firstname to a different class when an error occurs. is there a way to do this.

To add on i need the error message to be displayed as part of the summary as well as the label name in my case firstname should be red in color on error

Comment: To add on i need the error message to be displayed as part of the summary as well as the label name in my case firstname should be red in color on error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to define anything C# code. Instead MVC validation message consist their own class name as `field-validation-error`, so define the new custom style into it.

**Example :**

```
.field-validation-error {
    color:#F00;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: thanks @Kundan The problem is I am using  Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.UserDetails.EmailId, "Firstname", new { class = "validfail" }) however the error message also appears here as Firstname required. This error message should appear only in validations summary. Due to the error message the text firstname gets rewritten

Comment: Ok i got it i used   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.UserDetails.EmailId, Model.SignUpData.Body.FormLabels.EmailAddress)
The only other issue since this is a label i would like to generate label there

Comment: Ok solved it completely got a good post here https://gist.github.com/4418269/revisions which provides an extension method to use html.ValidationMessageFor to generate Labels followed by small tweaking that i made to ensure the error messages dont appear. solved the problem.